# Magento 2 : Update Order Summary Block On Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, blocks

I already look into this : [how to add fee to order totals in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2)

I need to added additional fee based on shipping address, So I used this plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="get_shipping_info" type="Company\Vendor\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

It sucessfully work and update value of fee in "quote" table in database.

But it not update fee value in checkout summary block.
[image]

How can I update this summary block, So it get updated value from database. 
How can I update block on selection of any payment method selection or any other way.

Comment: You want  to update Order Summary (right section) or on payment option?

Comment: @Dev yes, I want to update Summary (right section), because it not show updated value.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya: Are you able to solve this issue, sir?? I am also facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Summary section created on checkout-module. 
You can change **checkout_index_index.xml**, add item as '**quote**' & create js for
***Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/quote***

***Path - \vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml***

```
<item name="quote" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/quote</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quote</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

***\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\summary***

Also create **template** file in below path. 
  ***vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary***

You can override this file on you custom extension or update core files (Not recommended).
This might not be exact answer but might be workaround to you. 
Hope this help you.

Comment: this is not what I am asking, I need to just update summary block when payment section avilable, because it not show updated value from database. My field already avilable there.

Comment: Sorry for that. You should use **Knockout js** . Unfortunately, I don't have much idea about knockout js. Hope this link will help you.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140994/magento-2-event-observer-for-payment-method-selection/145513