# how to override tax amount with total collect when i click on one check box in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax-class

I am trying to **override tax** in **order review** in magento 2 when click on one `checkbox`. How to do that?

```
I have one form with checkbox in magento 2 onepage checkout page.
```

**My requirement is when I checked the checkbox the existing tax in the order Summary should be set to zero.**

Comment: I think that you need create a custom module to use your own tax calculation based on a parameter (checkox tick or not). Check core tax calculation.

Answer (score 2):

There are few steps which you need to perform in order to implement such functionality.

1. Insert checkbox field on the Checkout. There is comprehensive manual how to do that on [Official Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html).
2. Create controller which will trigger `collectTotals()` on `quote`. But at the same time, you'll have to rewrite `\Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax`, function `collect()`, in order to be able to control if tax should be applied or not.
3. And at the and, you'll need a little KnockoutJS which will help you to replace / reload `Review section` on Checkout. You can find a good explanation on [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140994/magento-2-event-observer-for-payment-method-selection/145513), which represents comprehensive manual how to work with KnockoutJS on Checkout.

Comment: Sinisa Nedeljkovic, Do you have full code for this answer?