# Magento 2 | Observer for checkout payment-method

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Is there an event for the checkout when you choose the payment method?

So when the site where you **choose the payment method** is called I want the event to trigger.

Thanks!

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140994/magento-2-event-observer-for-payment-method-selection. This may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote';
```

Observer:

```
quote.paymentMethod.subscribe(function(){console.log('test')}, null, 'change');
```

You will find plenty of observe there

```
var billingAddress = ko.observable(null);
var shippingAddress = ko.observable(null);
var shippingMethod = ko.observable(null);
var paymentMethod = ko.observable(null);
var totals = ko.observable(totalsData);
var collectedTotals = ko.observable({})
```

if you want to check the payment method inside a function, you can use first argument, like:

```
quote.paymentMethod.subscribe(function(method){console.log(method);}, null, 'change')
```

Comment: in which file ?

Comment: create a custom module