# Magento 2 : Data binding in Payment Method Selection

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, knockoutjs, magento-2.2.5, visibility

I want to display a custom field in "cash on delivery" payment method. I have created a custom module for this. But the field displays in all payment methods. Here is my code
html

```
<div class="payment-option opc-payment-additional rpo last" data-bind="fadeVisible: rpoVisible">
    <div class="payment-option-title field choice">          
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'RPO? (Optional)'"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-option-content" data-role="content">
        <div class="field">        
            <div class="control">                           
                <input type="text" id="referencepo-code" name="referencepo-code" value="" maxlength="16" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS file

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'knockout',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function ($, Component, ko,quote) {
        'use strict';


        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'NameSpace_Module/checkout/order-rpo-block'
            },
            initialize: function() {
                this._super();
                var self = this;
                self.rpoVisible = ko.observable(false);

                quote.paymentMethod.subscribe(function(method){
                     if(method.method == 'cashondelivery'){
                        self.rpoVisible = true;
                        console.log(method.method);
                    }else{
                        self.rpoVisible = false;
                    }
                }, null, 'change');



            },

        });
    }
);
```

Using this I got the payment method selection. But it is visibile in all payment methods. Please help me to resolve the issues.

Reference: [Magento 2 : Event Observer For Payment Method Selection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140994/magento-2-event-observer-for-payment-method-selection)